# Getting Xcode C++ linker error when trying to run an example using Armadillo library

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors, armadillo

I am trying to run an example program (comes with installation of Armadillo library) in Xcode and getting the following error:

> linker command failed with exit code -1 (use -v for invocation)

I can't figure out what's going in from Google searches.

I can build and run the program on the command prompt using:

> g++ example1.cpp -O2 -larmadillo

Here's my build setting:

[image]

Here's my search path to include the armadillo.h header:

[image]

My code is:

[image]

The actual error is:
[image]

Comment: Please add the actual error message from the linker. It should be right before the output you posted. Probably your code is also required to answer the question.

Comment: -O2 isn't a linker flag, and g++ accepts and convayes linker flags to the linker, it acts like a driver in that case. Is XCode useing clang these days? If you are using g++ in XCode the -O2 -larmadillo should be a compiler flag not a linker flag. I also assume that because it works from the shell that the library is in g++'s search paths already so unless Xcode is rewriting the entire PATH environment variable then it should be able to find it.

Comment: I have added the code in the original posting, and also the actual error.

Comment: I have tried building without the -O2 flag. It still provides the same error in Xcode. But I can build the code using the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build successfully by installing macport. 
Here are the steps:

1. Download and install macport from https://www.macports.org/.
2. Set Library path as /opt/local/lib.
3. Set Header path as /opt/local/include.
4. Set Other Linker Flags as -larmadillo.